Scale rotated SVGelements
Issue
I tried to create a little plugin that enables SVGelements to be scaled by dragging a little rect on top-right of each existing rect and circle. While this works fine for the red elements, it fails to do so properly for the blue one.
The desired behaviour is to scale the element, while keeping its proportion, using the bottom-left point as origin. Yet on the blue element it also rotates it around.
The blue element is already roated:
matrix(1 -0.5 0.5 1 0 0)

While the red elements are not:
matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)

My formula:
new m(a) = prev m(a) * largest movement of dx or dy as factor
new m(d) = new m(a) //to keep proportions
new m(e) = (prev m(a) - new m(a)) * prev(x) + prev m(e) //vertical position
new m(f) = (prev m(d) - new m(d)) * (prev(y) + prev(height)) + prev m(f) //horizontal position

Question
I assume that the already existing rotation on the blue element is causing my issue, however I fail to comprehend why. Since I merely adjust the translation(e,f) by the difference of scale(a,d), should that not work regardless of existing rotations?
For example I can just wrap the blue element in another g and add the changes on it, witout it rotating:
<g transform="matrix(1.2 0 0 1.2 -115 -25)">
  <rect x="380" y="320" width="40" height="40" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 -0.5 0.5 1 0 0)"></rect>
</g>

Simplified example


const
  _Drawing = document.querySelector('svg'),
  _Parent = _Drawing.querySelector('.VWS_DragAndDrop');

let
  _currentElement = null; //current "g.Dragging"

//add mousedown-event for dragging
_Drawing.onmousedown = function(event){
  if(event.target.tagName === 'rect' && event.target.parentNode.parentNode === _Parent){
    //set "g.Dragging" as dragging element
    _currentElement = event.target.parentNode;

    const
      tBBoxE = _currentElement.getBBox(),
      tBBoxR = _currentElement.referenceElement.getBBox(),
      tMatrix = _currentElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;

    //values on start to calculate the adjustments on move
    _currentElement.referenceOptions = {
      startX: event.clientX,
      startY: event.clientY,
      Bounds: {height: tBBoxR.height, w: tBBoxE.width * tMatrix.a, h: tBBoxE.height * tMatrix.d, x: tBBoxR.x, y: tBBoxR.y},
      Matrix: {a: tMatrix.a, b: tMatrix.b, c: tMatrix.c, d: tMatrix.d, e: tMatrix.e, f: tMatrix.f}
    }
  }
  else{
    //reset dragging element
    _currentElement = null
  }
};

//add mousemove for dragging
_Drawing.onmousemove = function(event){
  if(_currentElement){
    const
      tOriginalBBox = _currentElement.referenceOptions.Bounds,
      tOriginalMatrix = _currentElement.referenceOptions.Matrix,
      tCurrentMatrix = _currentElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix,
      tNewMatrix = _currentElement.ownerSVGElement.createSVGMatrix(),
      tCTM = _currentElement.ownerSVGElement.getScreenCTM()
      tC1 = {x: (_currentElement.referenceOptions.startX - tCTM.e) / tCTM.a, y: (_currentElement.referenceOptions.startY - tCTM.f) / tCTM.d},
      tC2 = {x: (event.clientX - tCTM.e) / tCTM.a, y: (event.clientY - tCTM.f) / tCTM.d},
      tDX = (tC2.x-tC1.x),
      tDY = (tC2.y-tC1.y);

    //current matrix as default
    tNewMatrix.a = tCurrentMatrix.a;
    tNewMatrix.b = tCurrentMatrix.b;
    tNewMatrix.c = tCurrentMatrix.c;
    tNewMatrix.d = tCurrentMatrix.d;
    tNewMatrix.e = tCurrentMatrix.e;
    tNewMatrix.f = tCurrentMatrix.f;

    //adjust matrix around p(bottom-left) while keeping proportions
    tNewMatrix.a = Math.max(tOriginalMatrix.a/100*((tOriginalBBox.w+tDX)*100/tOriginalBBox.w), tOriginalMatrix.d/100*((tOriginalBBox.h-tDY)*100/tOriginalBBox.h));
    tNewMatrix.d = tNewMatrix.a;
    tNewMatrix.e = (tOriginalMatrix.a - tNewMatrix.a) * tOriginalBBox.x + tOriginalMatrix.e; //vertical position
    tNewMatrix.f = (tOriginalMatrix.d - tNewMatrix.d) * (tOriginalBBox.y + tOriginalBBox.height) + tOriginalMatrix.f; //horizontal position

    //set new matrix to reference-element
    _currentElement.referenceElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tNewMatrix)

    //set new matrix to dragging-element
    _currentElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tNewMatrix)
  }
};

//add mouseup for dragging
_Drawing.onmouseup = _Drawing.onmouseleave = function(event){
  _currentElement = null
};

//adding dragging boxes to each "rect" and "circle"
document.querySelectorAll('rect, circle').forEach(function(element){
  const tElement = element;

  //create a "g.Dragging" inside "g.VWS_DragAndDrop"
  const tG = _Parent.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g'));
  tG.className = 'Dragging';
  tG.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)')
  tG.referenceElement = tElement;

  //apply the element's matrix to the new "g.Dragging"
  tG.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix)

  //create a "rect" to scale the reference-element while dragging that "rect"
  const
    tBBox = tElement.getBBox(),
    tLength = Math.floor(Math.min(tBBox.width, tBBox.height) / 10);

  const tRect = tG.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect'));
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', tBBox.x + tBBox.width - tLength);
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', tBBox.y - tLength*3);
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', tLength * 4);
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', tLength * 4)
})
<svg width="800" height="800" style="background-color: aqua">
  <style>
    .VWS_DragAndDrop rect{
      cursor: move;
      fill: grey;
      stroke: black
    }
  </style>

  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="15" fill="red" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" />
  <rect x="300" y="300" width="40" height="40" fill="red" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5 5)" />
  <rect x="380" y="320" width="40" height="40" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 -0.5 0.5 1 0 0)" />

  <g class="VWS_DragAndDrop" />
</svg>




When the element is already rotated, what are you thinking of as the point you call 'p' - at bottom left of the unrotated element or the position of its bottom left point after the original rotation?

The one which would be bottom-left if it was not rotated. Guess one would also call it the point opposite to the one which gets dragged.
If it is unclear I can expand it visually on myquestion.

Is there a reason for using svg transform with matrix rather than CSS properties?

Usually the svg we receive are pure svg and do not contain css. It is a svg converted dwg which already contains the given matrices.

@Lain while I am not good at matrices and can not answer your initial question of why it does not work, I suggest to: a) wrap your referenceElement in another g element. b) scale that g element instead of recalculating any matrix. c) use matrix.multiply once done. d) remove the wrapper g. e) rejoice.

@JavaScript: That reads nice. I shall give it a go, thank you.

Im not sure what u try archive but matrix is simply not rotate
If you want rotate element use rotate
Rotate takes 3 params:
degrees - rotation
x - position origin
y - position origin


const
  _Drawing = document.querySelector('svg'),
  _Parent = _Drawing.querySelector('.VWS_DragAndDrop');

let
  _currentElement = null; //current "g.Dragging"

//add mousedown-event for dragging
_Drawing.onmousedown = function(event){
  if(event.target.tagName === 'rect' && event.target.parentNode.parentNode === _Parent){
    //set "g.Dragging" as dragging element
    _currentElement = event.target.parentNode;

    const
      tBBoxE = _currentElement.getBBox(),
      tBBoxR = _currentElement.referenceElement.getBBox(),
      tMatrix = _currentElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix;

    //values on start to calculate the adjustments on move
    _currentElement.referenceOptions = {
      startX: event.clientX,
      startY: event.clientY,
      Bounds: {height: tBBoxR.height, w: tBBoxE.width * tMatrix.a, h: tBBoxE.height * tMatrix.d, x: tBBoxR.x, y: tBBoxR.y},
      Matrix: {a: tMatrix.a, b: tMatrix.b, c: tMatrix.c, d: tMatrix.d, e: tMatrix.e, f: tMatrix.f}
    }
  }
  else{
    //reset dragging element
    _currentElement = null
  }
};

//add mousemove for dragging
_Drawing.onmousemove = function(event){
  if(_currentElement){
    const
      tOriginalBBox = _currentElement.referenceOptions.Bounds,
      tOriginalMatrix = _currentElement.referenceOptions.Matrix,
      tCurrentMatrix = _currentElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix,
      tNewMatrix = _currentElement.ownerSVGElement.createSVGMatrix(),
      tCTM = _currentElement.ownerSVGElement.getScreenCTM()
      tC1 = {x: (_currentElement.referenceOptions.startX - tCTM.e) / tCTM.a, y: (_currentElement.referenceOptions.startY - tCTM.f) / tCTM.d},
      tC2 = {x: (event.clientX - tCTM.e) / tCTM.a, y: (event.clientY - tCTM.f) / tCTM.d},
      tDX = (tC2.x-tC1.x),
      tDY = (tC2.y-tC1.y);

    //current matrix as default
    tNewMatrix.a = tCurrentMatrix.a;
    tNewMatrix.b = tCurrentMatrix.b;
    tNewMatrix.c = tCurrentMatrix.c;
    tNewMatrix.d = tCurrentMatrix.d;
    tNewMatrix.e = tCurrentMatrix.e;
    tNewMatrix.f = tCurrentMatrix.f;

    //adjust matrix around p(bottom-left) while keeping proportions
    tNewMatrix.a = Math.max(tOriginalMatrix.a/100*((tOriginalBBox.w+tDX)*100/tOriginalBBox.w), tOriginalMatrix.d/100*((tOriginalBBox.h-tDY)*100/tOriginalBBox.h));
    tNewMatrix.d = tNewMatrix.a;
    tNewMatrix.e = (tOriginalMatrix.a - tNewMatrix.a) * tOriginalBBox.x + tOriginalMatrix.e; //vertical position
    tNewMatrix.f = (tOriginalMatrix.d - tNewMatrix.d) * (tOriginalBBox.y + tOriginalBBox.height) + tOriginalMatrix.f; //horizontal position

    //set new matrix to reference-element
    _currentElement.referenceElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tNewMatrix)

    //set new matrix to dragging-element
    _currentElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tNewMatrix)
  }
};

//add mouseup for dragging
_Drawing.onmouseup = _Drawing.onmouseleave = function(event){
  _currentElement = null
};

//adding dragging boxes to each "rect" and "circle"
document.querySelectorAll('rect, circle').forEach(function(element){
  const tElement = element;

  //create a "g.Dragging" inside "g.VWS_DragAndDrop"
  const tG = _Parent.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g'));
  tG.className = 'Dragging';
  tG.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)')
  tG.referenceElement = tElement;

  //apply the element's matrix to the new "g.Dragging"
  tG.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix)

  //create a "rect" to scale the reference-element while dragging that "rect"
  const
    tBBox = tElement.getBBox(),
    tLength = Math.floor(Math.min(tBBox.width, tBBox.height) / 10);

  const tRect = tG.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect'));
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', tBBox.x + tBBox.width - tLength);
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', tBBox.y - tLength*3);
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', tLength * 4);
  tRect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', tLength * 4)
})
<svg width="800" height="800" style="background-color: aqua">
  <style>
    .VWS_DragAndDrop rect{
      cursor: move;
      fill: grey;
      stroke: black
    }
  </style>

  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="15" fill="red" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" />
  <rect x="300" y="300" width="40" height="40" fill="red" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5 5)" />
<rect x="380" y="320" width="40" height="40" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) rotate(45 400 340)" />

  <g class="VWS_DragAndDrop" />
</svg>



Matrix explanation
It can take 6 params matrix(     )
While Rotate use simpley degrees and X Y position
Matrix uses
a: This is the horizontal scaling it stretches or compresses the element along the x-axis if a > 1, the element is stretched horizontally, and if a < 1, it's compressed
b: This represents the vertical skewing factor it skews the element along the y-axis. Skewing distorts the element by slanting it diagonally
c: This is the horizontal skewing factor it skews the element along the x-axis
d: This is the vertical scaling it stretches or compresses the element along the y-axis if d > 1, the element is stretched vertically, and if d < 1, it's compressed
e: This is the horizontal translation (X)
f: This is the vertical translation factor. It moves (translates) the element along the y-axis by f units
As you can see in matrix all thing works more like stretching or compressing not like rotate with preserving his natural shape
which can be calculated like
  top left corner: oldX=10 oldY=10
  newX = a * oldX + c * oldY + e = 3 * 10 - 1 * 10 + 30 = 50
  newY = b * oldX + d * oldY + f = 1 * 10 + 3 * 10 + 40 = 80

  top right corner: oldX=40 oldY=10
  newX = a * oldX + c * oldY + e = 3 * 40 - 1 * 10 + 30 = 140
  newY = b * oldX + d * oldY + f = 1 * 40 + 3 * 10 + 40 = 110

  bottom left corner: oldX=10 oldY=30
  newX = a * oldX + c * oldY + e = 3 * 10 - 1 * 30 + 30 = 30
  newY = b * oldX + d * oldY + f = 1 * 10 + 3 * 30 + 40 = 140

  bottom right corner: oldX=40 oldY=30
  newX = a * oldX + c * oldY + e = 3 * 40 - 1 * 30 + 30 = 120
  newY = b * oldX + d * oldY + f = 1 * 40 + 3 * 30 + 40 = 170


Could you explain what is meant by 'matrix is simply not rotate'?

Done in short Matrix is all about strething when rotate doesnt affect shape but just turn around object like its pinned to the table, but matrix can mimic it with strech all corners to position as its rotated.

Thank you for the reply and the example. Sadly it is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to be able to scale shapes which are already rotated by the matrix.

Could u explain why u need it to be rotated by matrix while its not his purpose?

Each transformation, like translation, rotation, scaling, and skewing, can be consolidated into one matrix. While you can keep repeating that the matrix is not for rotation, it does not make it true.
